# How to prevent duplicated requests for interceptor in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, request, angular-http-interceptors

I have an `interceptor` which intercepts the `401` error codes received from a `200 OK` message.

Unfortunately, I can't modify the `API` server to return `401` error instead of `200 OK` with error code.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  switchMap((result: any) => {
    //401 unauthorized error message
    if (result && result.body && result.body.isSuccess == false && result.body.errorCode == '401') {
      return this.unAuthorizedError(request, next);
    } else {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }),
  catchError((error) => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
        case 401:
        case 403:
          return this.unAuthorizedError(request, next);
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    return throwError(error);
  })
);
}
```

The problem is that every request is send twice and I assume that this is *probably* due to `switchMap` method which returns `next.handle(request)`.

I tried with `tap` method

```
 tap((result: any) => {
    //401 unauthorized error message
    if (result && result.body && result.body.isSuccess == false && result.body.errorCode == '401') {
      return this.unAuthorizedError(request, next);
    }
  }),
```

which sends the request only once, but when the token expires then `this.unAuthorizedError(request, next)` is not called.

Comment: Did you tried with `map` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right, what `next.handle(request);` does is to make the request again.

When `switchMap`'s inner observable is created, you already have a response, so I'd say you can replace `next.handle()` with `of(response)` so that it can be consumed by which part initiated the request:

```js
/* ... */
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  switchMap((result: any) => {
    //401 unauthorized error message
    if (result && result.body && result.body.isSuccess == false && result.body.errorCode == '401') {
      return this.unAuthorizedError(request, next);
    } else {
      return of(result);
    }
  }),
)
/* ... */
```

I wrote an article about Angular's `HTTPClientModule`, [here's](https://indepth.dev/posts/1142/exploring-the-httpclientmodule-in-angular#how-can-interceptors-retry-requests) the section in which I talk about interceptors.

Comment: Yes, just 2 minutes before you post the answer I managed to fix the issue. My version was with `from(of(result))`, but I think there is no longer need of `from` constructor.